# Fix content to the top of a page

Tags: html, css, fixed

I've got content that stays fixed to the top of the page when viewed at 711px wide:

[Click here to see the content fixed to the top of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTECP.jpg)

...but when I shrink the width of the browser to 397px wide, the content is pushed down into the center of the page as it scales proportionally:

[Click here to see the content move to the center of the page as it scales proportionally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF1Zl.jpg)

How can I keep my content **AT THE TOP OF THE PAGE** while it continues to scale proportionally?

Here is the code I'm using to format my HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Swiffy Output</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.4/runtime.js"></script>
  <script>
    swiffyobject = {
        "as3": true,
        "frameRate": 24,
        "frameCount": 109,
        "backgroundColor": -1,
        "frameSize": {
          "ymin": 0,
          "xmin": 0,
          "ymax": 14000,
          "xmax": 20000
        },
        "fileSize": 146782,
        "v": "7.4.1"
  </script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">

  </div>
  <script>
    var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
      swiffyobject, {});

    stage.start();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS :

```
#swiffycontainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Here's an example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa18cemf/1/)

You can see that the red block stays fixed the top of the container, no matter where you scroll in the viewport.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Hmmm... I tried adding it but it still isn't staying to the top.  <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a JSFiddle to show your full HTML. Link here https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yep!  Check now =)

Comment: Any ideas?  I still can't figure out how to get it to function properly.

Comment: @ShawnKilian - The HTML you've provided doesn't match what's in the images. I can't replicated your issue without the exact content.

Comment: That's because it's over 38,000 lines of Google Swiffy converter and it wouldn't let me add the code because it's too long so I gave you the top and bottom minus the Swiffy converted HTML.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle to demonstrate my point. And you can use that to apply to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body, #swiffycontainer {margin-top: 0; padding-top:0;}
```

Explanation: I would add this css to prevent browser predefined values, which browsers use in case it's not defined (like margin-top:8px for  in Chrome etc.)

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question (this answer was in the Low Quality Posts review queue).